# how to keep the energy in my spritekit node constant while keeping gravity

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, game-physics, skphysicsbody

I have a project where a ball rolls in between 2 hills and I want it to keep rolling forever. The hills are made by using spline points( There are 3 points, at (0,300), (375,0), and (750,300)). I have made sure that the ball and the ground has friction and restitution set to 0 but it still rolls back and forth, going up the hill less than it did the previous time.

Here is what the hills and ball look like: 
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6TYS.png)

**Edit:** I was asked to add some code so here is my GameScene.swift file:

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
var ball = SKShapeNode()

func createView(){
    removeAllActions()
    removeAllChildren()
    ball = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 20)
    ball.position = CGPoint(x:0, y:350)
    ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 20)
    ball.physicsBody?.restitution = 0
    ball.physicsBody?.friction = 0
    ball.physicsBody?.mass = 0.1
    ball.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0
    ball.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 0
    ball.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
    ball.fillColor = .red
    addChild(ball)
    ball.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: -400)
    ball.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = true


    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: -9.8)

    var splinepoints = [CGPoint(x: 0 , y: 0),
                        CGPoint(x: 0, y: 300),
                        CGPoint(x: 375, y: 0),
                        CGPoint(x: 750, y: 300)]
    let ground = SKShapeNode(splinePoints: &splinepoints, count: splinepoints.count)
    ground.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeChainFrom: ground.path!)
    ground.physicsBody?.restitution = 0.0
    ground.physicsBody?.friction = 0.0
    addChild(ground)



    let border = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: self.frame)
    border.friction = 0
    border.restitution = 0

    self.physicsBody = border


}
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    createView()
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    ball.physicsBody?.friction = 0
    ball.physicsBody?.restitution = 0
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(2), execute: {

    })
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(5), execute: {
        self.createView()
    })
}


}
```

Comment: Could you post some code? I need to see the code for the ball physics and the hill physics.

Comment: The SpriteKit physics are a fairly decent simulation of real life. The ball is rolling up the hill and expending some of its kinetic energy (CGVector). Then, it is gaining some of it, not all of it, back and rolling back up the other side. It isn't gaining all of its energy after expending it. Your code would have to add enough energy to the ball when it reaches the top of one side to get it back down and up to the other side.

Answer (score 0):

The physics in SpriteKit are a basic representation of real life. A lot of the principles taught in real-life physics courses are the same in SpriteKit.

Your ball is expending all its kinetic energy to roll up one hill. Rolling back down the hill doesn't give it enough energy to roll back up the other side. Eventually, the ball will stop rolling altogether and sit at the lowest point between the two hills.

Your code would have to add enough to the CGVector of your ball when it touches a node at the top of one side to get it to roll back down and up the other side to touch another node to add to the CGVector of the ball to get it to roll back down and up the first hill to touch the first node and add to the CGVector of the ball, etc. This should create an infinite rolling ball that never runs out of energy.